# Clear CardField in stripe react-native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

Clear value in CardField after success.

Adding payment module in my app where i'm getting payment token after adding card    detail to CardField. But i want to clear card fields after getting payment token and click on button that sends token to server. Please guide ho to achieve this.

```
<StripeProvider 
publishableKey={xxxxxxxxxxx}
merchantIdentifier="merchant.identifier"
urlScheme="your-url-scheme">
```

```
<CardField
postalCodeEnabled={true}
placeholders={{
number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
}}
cardStyle={{
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
textColor: '#000000',
borderWidth: 1,
//borderColor:'red'
}}
style={{
width: '100%',
height: 50,
marginBottom: 20
}}
onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
console.log('cardDetails', cardDetails);
if (cardDetails.complete)
    setCardInfo(cardDetails)
else
    setCardInfo(null)

}}
onFocus={(focusedField) => {
console.log('focusField', focusedField);
}}
/>
</StripeProvider>
```

---

Comment: You may use `ref` and call `clear` method on this. Example: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/pull/337